# Demandware OCAPI modify order

Tags: demandware

I've built a tiny program that helps Identify orders in Demandware that have incorrect status, e.g: (status: new, open, completed and shipping-status: not-shipped, shipped).

I basically just use order_search from OCAPI and compare the results with our ERP.

However now I want to automate some of the fixing of status, which would require me to use the /orders/{order_no} GET and PATCH calls, however when I do so, I get the following message:

```
{ type: 'AccessWithoutUserForbiddenException',
 message: 'An authenticated user is required in order to access resource.' }
```

According to the docs OAUTH for order_search uses: "Authentication via OAuth token.", however orders/{order_no} uses: "Authentication via OAuth token. A valid user is required."

So what would be the right strategy for becoming a valid user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a valid user for getting oAuth tokens is a Business Manager user. So please login to Business Manager and create a new user for your use cases and grant the necessary permissions.

After that you are able to execute the particular resources.

Christian

Comment: Thanks Christian, now I'm getting 

{ error: 'unauthorized_client',  error_description: 'Client id \'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\' has invalid credentials to use grant type \'urn:demandware:params:oauth:grant-type:client-id:dwsid:dwsecuretoken\'.' }

I believe that refers to my Client API/ID Key and not my Business Manager user (who is admin and should have the needed permissions). But I cannot see any documentation that tell me how to give my Client API Key/ID added permissions.

Comment: Alright, I just need to read the documentation a bit closer. Just figured out I was submitting the Authorization as user:pass and not user:pass:client_password.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using account.demandware.com as the host then it will throw below error

> { error: 'unauthorized_client', error_description: 'Client id
>   \'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\' has invalid credentials to use grant type
>   \'urn:demandware:params:oauth:grant-type:client-id:dwsid:dwsecuretoken\'.'
>   }

Instead you can change the host to your sandbox host. And try once again. It should work. I was also facing the same issue.

```
const key = new Buffer('business_manager_email_id' + ":" + 'business_manager_pwd' + ":" + 'client_pwd').toString("base64");
const options = {
    url: 'https://<sandbox_host>/dw/oauth2/access_token?client_id=your_client_id',
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Authorization': "Basic " + key,
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    body: "grant_type=urn:demandware:params:oauth:grant-type:client-id:dwsid:dwsecuretoken"
  };
```